# Run python script in Android aplication

Tags: java, python

I have Android application made in java and I need to call Python script and put there some parameters to its function. When I make apk. of this androdid app. how can I make Android device execute python script in it ?

Comment: I suppose you need to run Jython, or maybe try this 

https://www.pythoncentral.io/series/python-sl4a-android-scripting-layer-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a server out of python as backend with flask or django, and then call the server whenever your app needs to run the python script.